# how to append a unique key/value pair into a local file only in one unix command?

Tags: unix, key-value

I need to append a key/value pair value into a file, in such logic.

For example, the file contains such value already:

```
key1=value1

key2=value2
```

and if the new pair is `key3=value3`, it will be appended, but if it was `key1=value4`, the existing one would be updated.

Can such thing be done in ONE unix command ?

Comment: Must there be a blank line between lines?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "command". A UNIX command can be an arbitrarily long pipeline/sequence of simpler commands strung together.

There are any number of ways you could do it then, such as with:

```
awk '
    BEGIN    { s = "key1=value\n" }
    /^key1=/ { printf s; s = ""; next }
             { print }
    END      { printf s }
    ' infile >outfile && mv outfile infile
```

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
pax> printf '\nkey1=value1\nkey2=value2\nkey3=value3\n' | awk '
...> BEGIN    {s="key2=something_else\n"}
...> /^key2=/ {printf s;s="";next}
...>          {print}
...> END      {printf s}'

key1=value1
key2=something_else
key3=value3

pax> printf '\nkey1=value1\nkey2=value2\nkey3=value3\n' | awk '
...> BEGIN    {s="key4=something_new\n"}
...> /^key4=/ {printf s;s="";next}
...>          {print}
...> END      {printf s}'

key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
key4=something_new
```

You could probably also do it *without* a `&&` conjunction by using in-place `sed` editing, at the cost of a (probably) more complicated command.

Answer (score 0):

Not in one command, but in one line, (albeit word-wrapped below), 1st *update* 'key1':

```
echo  "key1=value4" | join -t '=' -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 keys.txt - \
    | sed 's/=[^=]*=/=/' | sponge keys.txt
cat keys.txt
```

Output:

```
key1=value4
key2=value2
```

Add 'key3':

```
echo  "key3=value3" | join -t '=' -j 1 -a 1 -a 2 keys.txt - \
    | sed 's/=[^=]*=/=/' | sponge keys.txt
cat keys.txt
```

Output:

```
key1=value4
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

Notes: I've started with *keys.txt* single spaced, as that's what **join** prefers.  **sponge** is from Debian's **moreutils** package.  A fringe benefit of **join** is that if first we input *key6*, and then later *key5*, **join** outputs the keys in numerical order.